# App gettin NullPointerException missing view in Layout

Tags: android

EDIT: The solution is in the comment below my question.

I'm unsure why my app is force closing.  Recently I had deleted an xml file (named 'directory.xml') and a java class file (named 'Directory.java'), and added in 4 xml and java files (directory1.xml, directory2.xml, directory3.xml, directory4.xml, Directory1.java, Directory2.java, Directory3.java, Directory4.java).  I updated the manifest to include these changes.  There are buttons I have on a layout called 'mainselect.xml'.  Four buttons are the buttons that have on-click listeners set up on them to call the java files (Directory1-4.java), which simply sets the content layout to the associated .xml file.  It all sounds so simple.

However, after looking at my LogCat, I noticed it said this:

```
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{around.lowell/around.lowell.Main}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at around.lowell.Main.onCreate(Main.java:22)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
 08-12 10:26:50.973: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1205):     ... 11 more
```

..which seems to be saying it can't start the Main activity ('main.xml' leads to 'mainselect.xml' by pressing a button, by the way).  However, I never changed main.xml or Main.java.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I should try?  Or perhaps someone sees a problem here?

Code:

Main.java ------

```
package around.lowell;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.content.Intent;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
// Used for color: 1 = color, 0 = not
public static int x = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Set up click listeners for all buttons
    View v1 = findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
    v1.setOnClickListener(this);

    View v2 = findViewById(R.id.colorCheck);
    v2.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.continueButton:
        Intent i1 = new Intent(this, MainSelect.class);
        startActivity(i1);
        break;
    case R.id.colorCheck:
        CheckBox check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.colorCheck);
        if(check.isChecked()) {
            // Main
            x = 1;
            LinearLayout l1a = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            l1a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
            View b1a = findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
            b1a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttoncolor);
            View b2a = findViewById(R.id.colorCheck);
            b2a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttoncolor); 
        } else {
            // Main
            x = 0;
            LinearLayout l1a = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
            l1a.setBackgroundColor(R.color.blackground);
            View b1a = findViewById(R.id.continueButton);
            b1a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorless);
            View b2a = findViewById(R.id.colorCheck);
            b2a.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.colorless); 
        }
        break;
    }
}
}
```

main.xml ----

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    >
   <ScrollView
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
<LinearLayout
     android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeText1"
        android:text="Welcome to the..."
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="70dip"
        android:gravity="center" 
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/welcomeText2"
        android:text="Around Lowell App"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="44sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/author"
        android:text="By: Mike Stowell"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:gravity="center"
    >
    </TextView>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/continueButton"
        android:text="Continue"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/buttoncolor"
        android:layout_height="40sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
    >
    </Button>
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/colorCheck"
        android:text="          Color "
        android:checked="true"
        android:background="@drawable/buttoncolor"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
    >
    </CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>
  </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The problem is in Main.java at line 22, what it the code there?

Comment: Looks like building error. Try to clean/build project to regenerate `gen` folder.

Comment: Genius! Cleaning it worked!  If you post that as an answer, I will give it the little green checkbox :).   EDIT:  Or I'll answer it myself, but I'll give you credit for it.  Thank you!  EDIT2:  So apparently I can't answer it myself for 8 hours.  I'll get it to later then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first possible reason for this NPE is that pointed by Pompe de velo, when there's no such view in layout. The second one is building error. Somehow eclipse plugin (or android building tool itself) sometimes generate wrong `R` file that can point to NPE or even views/layouts/strings etc messing.
This one is kinda of 2nd type coz we can see `continueButton` view in `main.xml`.

Answer (score 3):

Check for a null reference in your Main.java file, on the line 22.

Comment: Lines 21 and 22 are: `View v1 = findViewById(R.id.continueButton);` and `v1.setOnClickListener(this);`, which worked before I made changes.  I never edited the continueButton.

Comment: So v1 is null. Look if in the current layout there is a continueButton id.

Comment: The view `v1` is getting a null reference from your `findViewById()` function. Therefore, you can't call `setOnClickListener()` on it. Check that you have id `continueButton` in your layout xml file, which xml file should be the one you pass into the `setContentView()` function.

Comment: Well, why has this worked before I changed other portions of code?  `continueButton`, once clicked, loads up `MainSelect.xml`.

Comment: And yes, there is still a continueButton id in main.xml.

Comment: I do not know how your code look like, but you are clearly not initializing something in a correct way.

Comment: I'll post some code.  I'll put up my Main.java, main.xml, MainSelect.java, mainselect.xml, and AndroidManifest if you'd like.  Just give me a moment to do so.  I'll add it to the bottom of my original question.

Comment: @Mike: Put up the relevant code if you want. A simple check you can do already now is to make an if statement where you check if `v1 != null`.

Comment: I added an `if(v1 == null)` statement right after line 21 (all I had it do was display a random layout if this was the case), but when I ran the program, it forced closed and said that the error was still because of the line `v1.setOnClickListener(this);`.  In other words, I don't think v1 is null.  I could be wrong, I'm only a novice.

Comment: Test deleting both of those lines (21 and 22) and try again. You might have to clean your project - a reason can be that your xml files are screwed up.

Comment: Solution found - the project had to be cleaned again (I have no clue why, but its working fine now).  I'm guessing it was still trying to run some old code, and since I deleted/added new things, it couldn't run.  Thanks for you help though :).